# Is there a way to create a preview window in a panel/popup to show the compositor result with Python?

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a way to create a preview window in a panel/popup and show the “Render Result”? Would like to show updates when changes made in the compositor.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Are you specifically looking to do this with Python?

Comment: Yes, need it for addon if it's possible.